# How should I sanitize _GET variables that are only used on page?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, sanitization

I am fairly new to PHP and am using a couple of _GET variables to determine page layout/web service data and some other logic on the page. I am not storing the data or writing to a DB of any kind. What kind of sanitization should I be using for this?

For example, one var I'm using is like this:

```
$querystring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if(isset($_GET['semester']) && $_GET['semester'] != ''){
  $listxml = simplexml_load_file("http://path/to/webservice/?".str_replace('semester','term',$querystring));
```

What's going on there is if the querystring has the ?semester= set and not blank then I replace it with 'term' and pass through the querystring as is to a web service URL (the web service uses the term variable but the term variable interferes with wordpress and redirects to the posts page for that 'term' (tag/category in WP) so I pass it through WP as semester and then just change it to term for the web service call.

So in this case I'm not doing anything with the _GET except passing it on as is to a web service what the web service does with the querystring is out of my hands, but should I 'prep' it in any way for them?

--

I've also got cases similar to this:

```
$display = '';      
if (isset($_GET['display'])) {  
  $display = $_GET['display']; //set sort via querystring
} else {
  $display = 'interest'; //set to default by interest 
}
```

later:

```
<div id='byalphabet' class='<?php global $display; if($display != 'alphabet'){echo 'hide';} ?>'>
```

and

```
<div id="byinterest" class="<?php global $display; if($display != 'interest'){echo 'hide';} ?>">
```

--

Also using for some dynamic javascript:

```
$view = '';
if (isset($_GET['view'])) { 
  $view = $_GET['view']; //set view via querystring
}
```

Later:

```
<script>
<?php if ($view != ''){ $view = str_replace('/','',$view); ?>
jQuery('#<?php echo $view; ?>').trigger('click'); //activate view option accordion pane 
jQuery('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':jQuery('#<?php echo $view; ?>').offset().top - 50},500); //scrollTo view
</script>
```

--

Other cases include searching an array for a _GET value `array_search($_GET['major'], $slugs);` and redirecting a page using:

```
 $parts = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); //SEO friendly redirect
 Header( "Location: http://www.site.ca/programs/outline/".$parts[3]."/" );
```

Edit: I have read many of the suggested similar questions that popped up but they mostly refer to using the data in some other way such as inserting into a DB.

Comment: `?view=');alert('XSS` and you’re done.

Comment: @Gumbo It doesn't seem to work - is it possible PHP automatically changes quotes to being escaped because the output JS ends up \' instead of ' which breaks the attack. ie: `jQuery('#\');alert(\'XSS').trigger('click');`

Comment: Or using a better attack: `?view=');alert('XSS');jQuery('#` ends up with `jQuery('#\');alert(\'XSS\');jQuery(\'#').trigger('click');` which also just throws JS errors - I can't seem to get it to accept a quote as is with html entity, percent entity or direct quote char.. I know I still need to sanitize but does PHP take care of quotes automatically?

Comment: also, when I try to close the script tag and inject PHP the `<?php` gets turned into `<!-- php` so that doesn't work either.

Comment: This behavior is rather due to [magic quotes](http://php.net/security.magicquotes).

Comment: @Gumbo thanks. I definitely won't rely on that then as it's wrong and deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always sanitize input parameters. Even if you aren't using them in the database, you are still vulnerable to cross site scripting/XSS attacks.

```
<?php $view = $_GET['view'] ?>
<script>jQuery('#<?php echo $view; ?>').trigger('click');</script>
```

For example given the above code, everything is fine if `?view=page_one` because your JavaScript looks like `jQuery('#page_one').trigger('click');`.

But what if your querystring is `?view=hacked%27)%3B%20alert(document.cookies)%3B%20jQuery(%27%23page_one` - now your javascript looks like the following on the page:

```
jQuery('#hacked'); alert(document.cookies); jQuery('#page_one').trigger('click');
```

The `alert()` could just as easily be an AJAX request to send auth tokens, etc to a different server.

Ultimately the type of sanitizing you do depends on the context that you are using the input. In this example, you might want to make sure you escape single quotes for example, but what is  appropriate may differ between implementations.

Good article on sanitizing inputs here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/11/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/

Comment: thanks for the more helpful answer then the comment above. I've tried what you suggest and I get no JS alert... I am aware that I need to  sanitize anyway though. I'll check out the article, thanks.

Comment: my mistake, I tried it on an old version of the page without the view var. On the new version, it turns the ' into \' which still breaks the JS and raises a JS error in the console. `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #hacked'); alert('hello'); jQuery('#page_one` from the line: `jQuery('#hacked\'); alert(\'hello\'); jQuery(\'#page_one').trigger('click');`

Comment: It looks like you are escaping single quotes above. I also haven't seen your site or tested my code, it is just an example of a possible attack.

Comment: thats the thing, I'm not escaping anything, I'm outputting the _GET var as is, so does PHP automatically do this? It's also turning `<?php` into `<!-- php` so does PHP automatically sanitize attempted php tags as well into html comments? I can't find documentation on this anywhere.

Comment: PHP won't, but you might have a server extension that is doing XSS filtering.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's coming from Magic Quotes as suggested above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using PHP 5.4 and forgot about that for older version... should definitely migrate to something else since it's been removed in 5.4